# Creating raster from grid algebra expression using point attribute values?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a point shapefile representing groundwater production wells with annual pumpage values distributed over a general area. I'd like to create a raster layer with each cell representing the potential production impact weighted by distance using the following expression:

```
outputraster = SUM n/i (Xi/log10(Di))
```

Where 'Xi' is the annual production of well i and 'Di' is the distance in meters from well i.

Since there a multiple wells scattered over a wide area, the resulting raster cell values should be highest based on the density of wells in a given area, proximity to a given well, as well as the production value of a given well.

I've begun by creating a raster dataset, but am having trouble initiating the map algebra expression.

Can this calculation be performed within the raster calculator tool?

I have very little coding experience and my work with rasters extends only to interpolation and basic raster algebra expressions.

Comment: Firstly use (Di+10). You need to produce separate raster for each well and use cell statistics. Small script / model can do it.

Comment: whats the `SUM n/i` bit mean?

Comment: @FelixIP, what is the relevance of (Di+10)?

Comment: @Hornbydd, it's supposed to represent the summation operator (using the Sigma symbol).

Comment: To make it 1 at a point where distance equal 0 and log(0) doesn't exist